# CollapsingToolbarLayout - Inner Views hide and cut If be taller that screen height

Tags: android, image, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm going to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in my App View.
I put `ImageView` inside of it and fill it by Image like Images attached below.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/annonce.main.coordinator"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" >

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/flexible.example.appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="94dp"
        app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsingTextAppearance.Inverse" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/post_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/flexible.example.toolbar"
            style="@style/ToolBarWithNavigationBack"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@null" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Issue**

As you can see in images, When image height is greater than screen height! `CollapsingToolbarLayout` act like css property `overFlow:hidden` and cut the image

[image: Actual Size] [image: Result]

Comment: add `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to your `ImageView`.

Comment: @vrundpurohit no it does not seems to be related to `ImageView`, Cause if have more view below the image view, those gone too!

Comment: try to set fix height to your collapsingToolbar and imageview.

Comment: @Mehta I don't want it! I want to show image with real height of it here to users

Comment: if you want to show full image then  use android:scaleType="CenterCrop"

Comment: @Mehta no no. It's no related to `ImageView`, If i have some other view below image view, those gone too, As I said layout acts like `CSS` property `overFlow:hidden`

Comment: @MAY3AM: so you are saying that, if image is large then your rest of the components are not showing in screen. if yes then try to set app:layout_scrollFlags:"scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" to your collpasing toolbar and imageview

Comment: @Mehta It does not make any change :(